# unable to type in field using send keys protractor code

Tags: protractor

By using below code can any one suggest me how to send keys in text area

```
<div  *ngIf="showJournalsEditor">
  <form *ngIf="showJournalsEditor" [formGroup]="ToolsJournalsForm" Class="toolsJournalsFormClass" >
    <div [froalaEditor]="options" formControlName="journalsDescription" [style]="{'height':'320px'}">
    </div>
```

I have tried but getting below error

- Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10
  .0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: (Present code using a code block: prepend 4 (additional) blanks to each line, or mark the block of code and use "the {}-button" from the post editor's tool bar.)

Comment: This element just looks like the frame in which the editor is presented. There is probably another element present somewhere on the page, that takes the input. Try to look for elements containing something with `froala`.

Comment: Can you update the question with your protractor code?

Comment: i have tried with this code---------
 DescriptionField(){
           return element(by.css('div[formControlName="journalsDescription"]'));
       }

Answer (score 0):

You tried to select the element using 
`element(by.css('div[formControlName="journalsDescription"]')‌​);`

However `journalsDescription` element is not an input and you cannot focus on this element (as the error tells you: `cannot focus element`)

You need to select editable element and use it to `sendKeys`.

Example:
`element(by.css('div[formControlName="journalsDescription"] input')‌​); }`

Comment: hi suvroc i tired your code getting this error    ----------------- Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
    (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: Because it is only an example. It shouldn't work, because I don't know what is the structure of your page. Find what element is editable on the final page and point it in your selector

Comment: the above posted code is the complete code for description field there is no other related to description field ...that is only the problem